# How do I do a clean install (delete node_modules and install) with npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to get npm to unbuild all the modules under node_modules?  Something like npm rebuild that removes all build artifacts but doesn't rebuild them?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need to do this?

Comment: Thought you'd never ask.  I've been checking my node_modules directory into git as recommended in http://www.mikealrogers.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html.  When I add a new module or update a current one, I end up with build artifacts in git that shouldn't be there and have to clean them up.  I was thinking if I could clean them first the process would go a little more smoothly.

Comment: One quick note: now that NPM supports `shrinkwrap` (see http://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html), you can lock the versions of ALL your dependencies (instead of just the top level ones).

Comment: Thanks for `shrinkwrap`, this would help me solving some issues !

Comment: @BrandonTilley That's an improvement. However, you're still at the mercy of the online availability of npm. Perhaps a better solution would something like **npmbox** or **Sinopia**.

Comment: Not having this feature sucks for cross platform development as well. We develop on Mac and run CI on Linux, and need to remove the node_modules directory and completely re-install each time we do a build on Linux, which wastes a ton of time.

Comment: @JBCP you're doing it wrong. What you should be doing is installing modules in `packages.json` (using `npm --save`) and putting the `node_modules` directory in `.gitignore` (if using **git**). CI should not pull your node_modules, but execute `npm install`. Finally, if downloading from npm registry takes too long, use something like [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia) to cache it.

Comment: @BojanMarkovic - You are correct, this is how our projects are setup now. My comment above was from about a year ago. There are (were) a few projects that recommended committing node_modules into Git, but that is definitely not correct.

Answer (score 212):

You can just delete the node_module directory

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Comment: This would remove the source of the node_modules as well as the compiled output, so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If you have dependencies linked with npm link it might as well delete these modules source in it's source directory which can be quite painful...

Comment: I actually like this. Sometimes all you need is to remove the node_modules and reinstall them

Comment: @Kermit_ice_tea I agree with you. There's that many upvotes for a reason.

Comment: I added this to my `package.json`: `"clean": "rm -rf node_modules",
    "reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "rebuild": "npm run clean && npm install && npm run build",`. Seems to work well.

Comment: For windows>  rd  node_modules /s

Comment: @Lucas you should post this an an answer as it's the most suitable one

Comment: @JosephSerido Done, posted as answer below.

Comment: rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install

Comment: `rm .\node_modules -r -fo` for those who happen to be using Windows and PS

Answer (score 197):

There is actually special command for this job

```
npm ci
```

It will delete `node_modules` directory and will install packages with respect your `package-lock.json` file

More info: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html

Comment: Actually if you working with other team members and they updated some dependencies you should always do `npm ci` and not just `npm i`. The main reason that `npm i` also updates the lock file and this is probably that you don't want todo.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that they were building a fresh project, so just be careful with this when you are the one doing the updating of dependencies as the only way to update the package-lock file would be to run `npm i`.

Its a little misleading because it's called "clean install" but thats not necessarily what it does. Would be better named like rebase or something.

If you rely on your project version to be in package.json as well, package-lock doesn't get updated either until you do an `npm i`, though thats not as big of a deal.

Answer (score 100):

I added this to my package.json:

```
"build": "npm build",
"clean": "rm -rf node_modules", 
"reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install", 
"rebuild": "npm run clean && npm install && npm run build",
```

Seems to work well.

Comment: `clean` has to be defined in the package.json !

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz ? That's what my answer says above?

Comment: use 'rm -rf node_modules' in case linux based machine, incase of windows 'rmdir /s /q node_modules'

Comment: To use these you can't call "npm clean" since clean isn't one of the accepted names on npm. You need to do "npm run clean".

Comment: Note that your `reinstall` is now built-in command: `npm ci`

Comment: `npm ci` does not simply delete and reinstall all modules; it is mainly meant for deploy envs, and doesnt modify the package-lock.

Comment: `rm -rf` will not work on windows. Script's should be multiplatform compatible.

Answer (score 30):

Try 
https://github.com/voidcosmos/npkill

```
npx npkill
```

it will find all node_modules and let you remove them.

[image: npkill]

Comment: thank you for your answer. out of curiosity,  could you share how did you do the animation? :)

Comment: @lww https://github.com/vvo/gifify

Answer (score 12):

`npm ci` works for this scenario, but only when your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are in sync, which might not always be the case if you have been working on either one to resolve conflicts quickly or are updating on the directory level by removing directories/symbolic links. A comprehensive answer to the question would be this..

1. Edit the `package.json` with what ever you want and remove what you dont need.
2. Generate the `package-lock.json` like this, `npm install --package-lock-only`
3. Run `npm ci`. This should remove all artifacts and shouldn't rebuild them.

Comment: For anyone who ran this command and it failed, try `npm ci --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 9):

You can take advantage of the 'npm cache' command which downloads the package tarball and unpacks it into the npm cache directory.

The source can then be copied in.

Using ideas gleaned from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/npm-/mwLuZZkHkfU I came up with the following node script. No warranties, YMMV, etcetera.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
exec = require('child_process').exec,
util = require('util');

var packageFileName = 'package.json';
var modulesDirName = 'node_modules';
var cacheDirectory = process.cwd();
var npmCacheAddMask = 'npm cache add %s@%s; echo %s';
var sourceDirMask = '%s/%s/%s/package';
var targetDirMask = '%s/node_modules/%s';

function deleteFolder(folder) {
    if (fs.existsSync(folder)) {
        var files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            file = folder + "/" + file;
            if (fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()) {
                deleteFolder(file);
            } else {
                fs.unlinkSync(file);
            }
        });
        fs.rmdirSync(folder);
    }
}

function downloadSource(folder) {
    var packageFile = path.join(folder, packageFileName);
    if (fs.existsSync(packageFile)) {
        var data = fs.readFileSync(packageFile);
        var package = JSON.parse(data);

        function getVersion(data) {
            var version = data.match(/-([^-]+)\.tgz/);
            return version[1];
        }

        var callback = function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            var dependency = stdout.trim();
            var version = getVersion(stderr);
            var sourceDir = util.format(sourceDirMask, cacheDirectory, dependency, version);
            var targetDir = util.format(targetDirMask, folder, dependency);
            var modulesDir = folder + '/' + modulesDirName;

            if (!fs.existsSync(modulesDir)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(modulesDir);
            }

            fs.renameSync(sourceDir, targetDir);
            deleteFolder(cacheDirectory + '/' + dependency);
            downloadSource(targetDir);
        };

        for (dependency in package.dependencies) {
            var version = package.dependencies[dependency];
            exec(util.format(npmCacheAddMask, dependency, version, dependency), callback);
        }
    }
}

if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(process.cwd(), packageFileName))) {
    console.log(util.format("Unable to find file '%s'.", packageFileName));
    process.exit();
}

deleteFolder(path.join(process.cwd(), modulesDirName));
process.env.npm_config_cache = cacheDirectory;
downloadSource(process.cwd());
```

Comment: I find it very strange that such a basic functionality, that is actually recommended by npm, requires a hack to achieve. What does everyone else do? Just ignore the recommendation and use `npm install`?

Answer (score 6):

In a word *no*.

In two, *not yet*.

There is, however, an open issue for a `--no-build` flag to `npm install` to perform an installation without building, which could be used to do what you're asking.

See [this open issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6529).

Answer (score 5):

For windows environment:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rmdir /s /q node_modules",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have added few lines inside package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "clean": "rmdir /s /q node_modules",
  "reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install",
  "rebuild": "npm run clean && npm install && rmdir /s /q dist && npm run build --prod",
  ...
}
```

If you want to `clean` only you can use this `rimraf node_modules`.

Comment: For Mac or Linux users:
`"clean": "rm -rf node_modules",`

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
"clean": "rm -rf ./node_modules package-lock.json .cache dist && npm i",
}
```

Comment: it is better to use `rm -r` using the `f` parameter is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

## `npm ci`

As [mentioned by FDisk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081837/6908282) You can use `npm ci` to remove `node modules` folder and re-install npm packages from scratch.

## `npm prune`

Alternatively, you can also use `npm prune` to remove extraneous packages installed inside your node_modules folder that aren't defined inside the package.json

---

References:

- [How to clean node_modules folder of packages that are not in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122629/6908282)
- [NPM prune after NPM ci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51332145/6908282)