# How to clean node_modules folder of packages that are not in package.json?

Tags: node.js, package, npm

Assume I install project packages with `npm install` that looks into `package.json` for modules to be installed. After a while I see that I don't need some specific module and remove its dependency from `package.json`. Then I remove some other modules from `package.json` because they are not needed anymore and others are replaced with alternatives.

Now I want to clean `node_modules` folder so that only modules listed in `package.json` stay there and the rest must go, something like `npm clean`. I know I can remove them manually but would like to have some nice ready to use sugar functionality for that.

Comment: One thing all answers below and OP did not mention is: Make sure you have **package lock** before deleting `node_modules`, otherwise npm will re-evaluate the package.json and gives you the latest package versions, which with package that does not follow semver properly can become a nightmare

Comment: Fwiw, the new package manager pnpm keeps node_modules clean, only makes folders for your top level deps.  Give it a try!

Answer (score 518, accepted):

I think you're looking for `npm prune`

> `npm prune [<name> [<name ...]]`
>
> This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is
>   provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are
>   removed.
>
> Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the
>   parent package's dependencies list.

See the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune

Comment: As far as I know, in new NPM version, all the dependencies are located at the root `node_modules` folder, and not as before, where each dependency had it's own dependencies install in their own `node_modules` folders..with countless copies of the same dependencies... so does `npm prune` takes this into consideration? because those deep-dependencies aren't written on the main `package.json` of your project.. prune must look recursively.

Comment: @vsync Duplication reduction is achieved with the command `npm dedupe` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe . It tries to simplify the node tree by moving dependencies up the tree.

Comment: I've seen NPM prune fail to delete things usually screwing up when my corporate repository has something borked in it.  Then I have to rm-rf.  It would be nice if there was a "blow everythin away then reget everything all in one go" command

Comment: NPM 7 and Yarn 2+ will automatically prune on install, this command is not needed anymore normally

Comment: `npm ci` seems to be a recently introduced command for this job. reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081837/6908282

Answer (score 340):

You could remove your node_modules/ folder and then reinstall the dependencies from package.json.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

This would erase all installed packages in the current folder and only install the dependencies from package.json. If the dependencies have been previously installed npm will try to use the cached version, avoiding downloading the dependency a second time.

Comment: Yes, I know I can use this method but I am curious why there is still no more elegant solution for that.

Comment: Are there really no npm command to delete node_modules other than deleting the folder?

Comment: On windows platform, it fails while deleting node_modules thru Explorer or command line (since the path to some modules are longer than 256). There should be npm command to do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: @RaviKumar Try install rimraf first through npm. It handles deleting folders very well.

Comment: Or using `rmdir node_modules /s /q` on Windows. http://superuser.com/a/179661/440976

Comment: I think, this answer is missing a very important point: **if you are constrained by the traffic (i.e. you have the expensive per-megabyte-paid connection like mobile) and you have a lot of modules, this may cost you**, while the `prune` option does require you to have internet connection at all.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` is slower but the only actual reliable way. `npm update && npm prune` will, e.g., [not remove packages referenced by `peerDependencies`](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10442).

Comment: Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.

Answer (score 135):

> Due to its folder nesting Windows can’t delete the folder as its name is too long. To solve this, install RimRaf:

```
npm install rimraf -g

rimraf node_modules
```

Comment: Or just `rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` will not work on windows. See this solution: http://superuser.com/a/179661/440976

Comment: win7 x64 rimraf worked great through PowerShell.. thanks

Comment: Best solution for Windows 10 64-bit via CMD

Comment: rm -rf node_modules didnt work for me on Windows 10. But rimraf worked for me

Comment: This relies on rimraf being in the system which isn't always wanted. It's `npx rimraf node_modules` for one-time job.

Comment: This solution worked for angular latest versions

Answer (score 65):

From version 6.5.0 `npm` supports the command `clean-install` (`ci`) to hard refresh all the packages.

Please, see the references:

- `npm` 6.x: [npm-ci | npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci).
- `npm` 7.x: [npm-ci | npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci).
- [npm Blog Archive: Introducing `npm ci` for faster, more reliable builds](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. When I update node, the first thing that happens is "looks like you you've changed your environment since running 'npm install'". Since I'm already in the console, it's easiest to just do clean-install rather than messing around deleting folders first etc.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `npm ci` is also great for continuous integration. It runs faster if you don't have a node_modules directory, so on our servers we backup the previous build by renaming node_modules to something else (for example, node_modules_backup. If a backup already exists, delete it first and then rename). We then run `npm install` as a hassle-free swift package update solution.

Comment: thanks @Nadav, but to be fair the question was asked in 2014 and at the time there was no such a thing, so the author approved the best-at-the-time answer :)

Answer (score 49):

simple just run

```
rm -r node_modules
```

in fact, you can delete any folder with this.

like **rm -r AnyFolderWhichIsNotDeletableFromShiftDeleteOrDelete**.

just open the **gitbash** move to root of the folder and run this command

Hope this will help.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get a "permission denied" error (using gitbash.

Comment: open gitbash in administrator mode. i guess that will help.
or change folder permission level settings

Comment: This would delete _**all**_ packages. The OP clearly says "I want to clean node\_modules folder so that only modules listed in package.json stay there".

Comment: in that case my friend you can simply do "npm uninstall package_name " or --save as sufix that will delete its entry from package.json file as well. 



npm uninstall package_name (delete package)

npm uninstall package_name --save (delete package and remove entry from dependencies in package json)

npm uninstall package_name --save-dev (delete package and remove entry from devdependencies in package json)

Answer (score 31):

First globally install rimraf

```
npm install rimraf -g
```

go to the path using cmd where your node_modules folder and apply below command

```
rimraf node_modules
```

Comment: good answer, but installing a package to uninstall other ones is not a good idea though. `npm prune` is an ideal solution.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to remove the node_module folder from your project this is the best and easy way.

Answer (score 16):

Just in-case somebody needs it, here's something I've done recently to resolve this:

**npm ci** - If you want to clean everything and install all packages from scratch:

-*It does a clean install:* if the node_modules folder exists, npm deletes it and installs a fresh one.

-*It checks for consistency:* if package-lock.json doesn’t exist or if it doesn’t match the contents of package.json, npm stops with an error.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci

**npm-dedupe** - If you want to clean-up the current node_modules directory without deleting and re-installing all the packages

Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree, where they can be more effectively shared by multiple dependent packages.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-dedupe

Answer (score 14):

The best article I found about it is this one: https://trilon.io/blog/how-to-delete-all-nodemodules-recursively

All from the console and easy to execute from any folder point.

But as a summary of the article, this command to find the size for each `node_module` folder found in different projects.

```sh
find . -name "node_modules" -type d -prune -print | xargs du -chs
```

And to actually remove them:

```sh
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

The article contains also instructions for windows shell.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried npm prune?

it should uninstall everything not listed in your package file

https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-prune.html

Answer (score 7):

I have added few lines inside package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "clean": "rmdir /s /q node_modules",
  "reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install",
  "rebuild": "npm run clean && npm install && rmdir /s /q dist && npm run build --prod",
  ...
}
```

If you want to `clean` only you can use this `rimraf node_modules` or `rm -rf node_modules`.

It works fine

Answer (score 7):

You can also use **npx** in combination with **rimraf** to remove all node modules with one command, so you don't have to install rimraf first.

So go to the path where your node_modules folder is located by using cmd (in case you are not there already) and run the following command

```
npx rimraf node_modules
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently upgraded Angular from 14 to 15, and found that I need to do:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

If I don't do cache clean, the install will success locally, but failed when run deploy on server. This is because local install will use local cached package to install. be aware. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows User, alternative solution to remove such folder listed here: http://ask.osify.com/qa/567

Among them, a free tool: **Long Path Fixer** is good to try: http://corz.org/windows/software/accessories/Long-Path-Fixer-for-Windows.php

Answer (score 1):

Use following command instead of npm install

```
npm ci
```

Comment: npm ci installs the packages listed in shrinkwrap.json

Comment: This is correct answer. "ci" (stands for clean-install) will remove node_modules/ first and then install all in one command.

Answer (score 0):

rimraf is an package for simulate linux command [rm -rf] in windows. which is useful for cross platform support. for install its CLI:

```
npm install rimraf -g
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply should run this
`rm -rf node_modules/`
`npm install`