# How to remove all packages from node_modules that are listed in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

Basically I am looking for the "opposite" of `npm prune` or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122342/how-to-clean-node-modules-folder-of-packages-that-are-not-in-package-json) SO question.

More specifically:

I am looking to clean up `node_modules` folder from all packages that are listed in my root `package.json` file. Sort of a fresh start before `npm install`.

The reason I don **not** want to simply `rm -rf node_modules/` is because I have some local modules that I don't want to get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

it isnt possible to remove at once all in your package.json you could write shell script to loop through. or you can check `npm ls` and then remove `npm rm <name>` or npm uninstall  each manually. and to update it in package.json simultaneously `npm rm <name> --save`

Comment: you probably don't need the `--save` if you just want to clean up before reinstalling

Comment: yes thats right but in case you just want to remove few so i mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to have your permanent (local) modules in a directory of a higher level:

```
-node_modules (local)
-my_project
|-node_modules (npm)
```

That way, when you wipe the node_modules directory, the outer local modules remain.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, there's no native npm command to do that.

I've taken [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9283646/599912) and modified the command:

```
$ npm ls | grep -v 'npm@' | awk '/@/ {print $2}' | awk -F@ '{print $1}' | xargs npm rm
```

This lists all of your local packages and then `npm rm` them one by one.

For convenience, if you want, you can add the following line to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "uninstall": "npm ls | grep -v 'npm@' | awk '/@/ {print $2}' | awk -F@ '{print $1}' | xargs npm rm"
}
```

and then run

```
$ npm run uninstall
```