# Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to run Webpack on a project and I am getting multiple errors

```
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
...
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts
error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
```

I should have all my typings installed so I am not sure where these are coming from. I tried copying over a package.json from a project that compiles but it didn't help. What am I missing?

My tsconfig looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I am getting the same kind of errors with @types/core-js at 0.9.35

Could be something else..

EDIT

There has been some changes on the repo last week. You can read the issue on github and see the changes via these links:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15104

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/15108/commits/f2c5c990e448550fcebec071c25e6a1e5766dde7

My solution was to change

`"lib": ["es5", "dom"]` to `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]` in the `compilerOptions` object in my tsconfig files.

By doing this I made the errors disappear without downgrading to 0.9.35

Note: You dont need to change the target (mine is still es5)

Comment: it works for me. However, I have 2 computers both running VS2015 Pro with latest update and packages, one had problem which could be fixed by this answer, and the other does not need. A bit strange.

Comment: Maybe one is not looking in the right place to the tsconfig? Or maybe one had the upgraded version of the types and one had another.

Comment: Does changing to ES6 not break IE 11 operation?  In other words what are the ramifications in regards to ES6 and browser compliance?

Comment: as long as the target is still es5, your code should be able to run in IE.

Answer (score 8):

For me the answer was...

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "lib": [
    "es2016",
    "dom"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 5):

downgrade your `@types/core-js` to 0.9.35.

I was just having the same problem after upgrading to 0.9.37.

Comment: I downgraded my version to 0.9.36 and it works. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm loading version 0.9.35 fixed this for me.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgraded to "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35" and added lib to my compilerOptions.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    ......
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    ........
    "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "dom"
    ]
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ...
]
}
```

Comment: After you add "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35", do you need to run an npm command? like npm update or something?
This is still not working for me.

Comment: I removed the 'npm_modules' folder using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122342/how-to-clean-node-modules-folder-of-packages-that-are-not-in-package-json/45269399#45269399) and then again ran command 'npm install'

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by adding this code in tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
  "lib": ["es2017", "dom"] //Please add this code in your tsconfig.json
```

},
   "exclude": [
         "node_modules"
     ]
}