# Accidentally hitt CMD+B in Sublime Text 3 and it broke my project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out, I have a node.js project with a angular front-end, that I version on Git.

Sometime yesterday I accidentally hit cmd+B in Sublime Text not knowing what that command was, and ever since I'm having a bunch of problems building the project with npm run build.

The output from the build process now is

> `ERROR in [default]
>   /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/auth/signin.component.ts:23:40
>
> ```
> Property 'token' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/auth/signin.component.ts:24:41
>
> Property 'userId' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/auth/signup.component.ts:75:40
>
> Property 'token' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/auth/signup.component.ts:76:41
>
> Property 'userId' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/questions/question-create.component.ts:141:50
>
> Property 'obj' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/user/settings/user.change-pass.component.ts:45:36
>
> Property 'message' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/assets/app/user/settings/user.setting.component.ts:88:36
>
> Property 'message' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts:44:37
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts:19:99
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts:21:73
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts:31:123
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts:13:22
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts:40:48
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts:42:64
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts:35:17
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts:36:45
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts:16:17
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:106:66
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:122:100 
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:148:66
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts:150:100 
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:12:16
>
> Cannot find name 'Map'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts:13:16
>
> Cannot find name 'Set'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:53:48
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts:61:64
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts:14:33
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts:28:24
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts:8:52
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts:10:22
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts:279:61
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:78:98
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:157:108
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:227:114
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:297:90
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:367:49
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts:386:69
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts:408:58
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@angular/router/src/utils/collection.d.ts:35:57
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:47:35
>
> Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:350:47
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:351:51
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:352:33
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:353:33
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:354:33
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:355:60
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:356:59
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:357:64
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:357:96
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:358:59
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:359:57
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:360:58
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:361:57
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:362:60
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:362:116
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:363:41
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:365:80
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:366:77
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:367:75
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:368:72
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:431:5
>
> Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:456:38
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:464:58
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:465:58
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:467:47
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:468:68
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:472:39
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:474:47
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:494:54
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:495:44
>
> Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:511:45
>
> Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:512:42
>
> Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:627:17
>
> Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:642:31
>
> Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:646:38
>
> Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:646:52
>
> Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:657:34
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1280:33
>
> Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1284:40
>
> Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1288:47
>
> Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1292:37
>
> Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1296:35
>
> Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1300:34
>
> Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1304:36
>
> Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1308:35
>
> Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1312:36
>
> Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1316:34
>
> Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1320:40
>
> Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1324:40
>
> Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1328:40
>
> Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2059:33
>
> Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2063:40
>
> Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2067:47
>
> Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2071:37
>
> Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2075:35
>
> Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2079:34
>
> Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2083:36
>
> Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2087:35
>
> Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2091:36
>
> Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2095:34
>
> Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2099:40
>
> Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2103:40
>
> Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2107:40
>
> Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/ng2-uploader/src/directives/ng-file-drop.ts:81:25
>
> Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/ng2-uploader/src/directives/ng-file-drop.ts:120:23
>
> Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/ng2-uploader/src/directives/ng-file-select.ts:94:23
>
> Property 'from' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:10:65
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:66:59
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:66:69
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts:40:30
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts:41:25
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:7:58
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:7:68
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:9:8
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:10:25
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> ERROR in [default] /Users/user_dev/Documents/company/github/company_project_x/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:10:35
>
> Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>
> `
> ```

I have tried reverting to the last known commit, downloading the project and creating a new folder in it to initialise and compile (from previous commits that should work) but I always end up with these errors.

I also noticed that the Sublime Build command filled my folders with .js files, that were redundant as my project uses .ts files. So I've removed them in hopes of clearing things up but still no luck.

Does anyone have a macic trick for me? :)

Comment: maybe it's nothing to do with CMB+B? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738623/cannot-find-name-propertykey https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15140

Comment: thanks, good tip but none of the solutions suggested there had any effect :/

Comment: bygga. ok, so if you `git clone` your repo again, checkout a working commit *before* installing node modules and you still get errors, then it's something outside your code. I'd maybe try switching node versions, just to ensure there are no globally installed modules and try again. ..unless you recently updated any global modules?

Comment: No, I haven't done any upgrades. I am on Node.js 6.9.5, so I can try to upgrade to 6.1.0

Comment: last thought.. unless you are using yarn or shrinkwrap you could be installing an updated module. Maybe try setting versions in package.json to absolute versions?

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if that helps