# Cannot find name 'PropertyKey' in index.d.ts (MS Visual Studio and angular)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

i followed this [guide](http://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/12/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017/) to use angular with .net mvc but i have no success. i tried the these solution below still cannot resolve the issue. I have the error in the file

> TypeScript\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738623/cannot-find-name-propertykey)

Here is the tsconfig and package.json both located in the root of the project.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* depend on the `@types/core-js` package. It is almost entirely redundant with the official TypeScript declarations included explicitly by way of

```
"lib": ["dom", "es2017"]
```

Using

```
"target": "es2017"
```

Also implies the same but explicitly specifying `--lib` as you have done is in good practice.

By overlapping with the latest declarations for the DOM and ECMAScript APIs the `@types/core-js` package, which roughly describes the structure of the polyfills provided by the `core-js` package, introduces an extremely high likelihood that declarations will conflict . Furthermore, the `@types/core-js` package is far less well-maintained than the `lib.es2017.d.ts` declarations you are already referencing.

Since you have listed your dependencies, and `@types/core-js` is not among them, it is likely being installed transitively. Since it contains global declarations, this is inherently problematic.

To resolve the issue, set the `"types"` property explicitly in your `tsconfig.json`. This governs the inclusion of ***global*** `@types` packages by the TypeScript compiler.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],

    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"]
  }
}
```

To include *global* `@types` declarations in such a setup, you must reference them in the newly added property.

Here is an example:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["bootstrap", "mocha"],

    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"]
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Be sure to explicitly *depend on* any `@types` packages by installing them with your package manager. Relying on transitive dependencies will lead to non-deterministic builds, unpredictable CI failures, and general chaos.
2. The `@types/core-js` package contains declarations for APIs that extend beyond the scope of ES2017. If you need access to these types, change the spec numbered value of `--lib` to `esnext` as in

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "lib": ["dom", "esnext"]
     }
   }
   ```
3. You have a number of outdated and discrepant dependencies. In particular, `"typings": "^1.3.2"`, is *very* old and should be updated. `typings` should also be installed as a *development* dependency, a feature supported by all package managers including `typings` itself.