# PhpStorm complains that a type is not found but still can open the file defining it

Tags: angularjs, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I have an AngularJS project written in TypeScript with PhpStorm. 
When compiling with Webpack, I get the following error :

> Error:(42, 43) TS2694:Namespace 'angular' has no exported member 'angularFileUpload'.

So there is a problem somewhere. But what bugs me is that PhpStorm is still able to resolve the type and to open the file defining it while complaining that the type cannot be resolved :

Here's an animated gif showing the behavior:
[image]

I have the same problem with another library.

In fact, it seems that typings trying to extend the `ng` namespace are overridden by something later on, and I don't find where.

I have included `@types/ng-file-upload` and defined the types root in my tsconfig like shown in the animated gif.

Thanks in advance for any advise you could give me.

**EDIT** :

Here's the content of my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "...",
  "repository": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp build --theme=default",
    "gulp:prod": "gulp build --theme=default --env=prod",
    "gulp:watch": "gulp build --theme=default --watch",
    "gulp:watch:prod": "gulp --theme=default --watch --env=prod",
    "webpack:native:watch": "webpack --config build/webpack/config/root.config.ts --env.app=native --env.target=julien-localhost --watch",
    "webpack:native:prod": "webpack --config build/webpack/config/root.config.ts --env.app=native --env.target=production --env.env=prod",
    "webpack:angularjs/admin:watch": "webpack --config build/webpack/config/root.config.ts --env.app=angularjs/admin --env.target=julien-localhost --watch",
    "webpack:angularjs/admin:prod": "webpack --config build/webpack/config/root.config.ts --env.app=angularjs/admin --env.target=production --env.env=prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-aria": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-clipboard": "~1.6.2",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.7.1",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.9",
    "angular-messages": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-moment-picker": "^0.10.2",
    "angular-resource": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-translate": "~2.17.0",
    "angular-ui-notification": "^0.3.6",
    "angular-ui-router.statehelper": "~1.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "inversify": "^4.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-backstretch": "^2.1.16",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mainloop.js": "^1.0.4",
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "^3.1.5",
    "moment": "~2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "ng-file-upload": "~12.2.13",
    "parsleyjs": "^2.8.1",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "raven-js": "^3.26.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "satellizer": "^0.15.5",
    "scrollmonitor": "^1.2.4",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/angular": "~1.6.43",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.11",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.4",
    "@types/angular-ui-notification": "0.0.4",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "^1.1.40",
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
    "@types/modernizr": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/ng-file-upload": "~12.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.34",
    "@types/q": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/reflect-metadata": "^0.1.0",
    "@types/source-map": "~0.5.7",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.30",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.15",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "browser-sync": "~2.23.6",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "chalk": "^2.3.1",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^4.4.0",
    "clone": "2.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.4.1",
    "force-case-sensitivity-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.1",
    "gulp-angular-embed-templates": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-yaml-packages": "~1.0.15",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "~2.30.1",
    "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
    "ngtemplate-loader": "~2.0.1",
    "node-neat": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "~3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "~3.5.3",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.1",
    "webpack-strip-block": "github:jballant/webpack-strip-block"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, show me your package.json file content

Comment: Side note: pay attention to the full error message (the code before the actual message) -- it says `TS2694`... which means it is produced by TypeScript service and not PhpStorm itself...

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I said `When compiling with Webpack, I get the following error`. I don't find a solution to the error, that's the first thing. But the one that motivated my question is the behavior of phpstorm. But I'm really stuck with the error anyway. If you have an idea..

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666667/error-ts2694-namespace-angular-has-no-exported-member-xxx-after-upgrading - your issue can be related to having several versions of angular typings installed

Comment: Thanks for the link, I did some research before posting a new question and I've seen this question. That is why I said `In fact, it seems that typings trying to extend the ng namespace are overridden by something later on, and I don't find where.`. I've spent a good amount of time trying to remove some of the dependencies, with no luck. I suspected satellizer to be the cause of the problem because they define angular typings in their npm module, but I still get the error even after removing the dependency...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem...

My `tsconfig.json` file contains:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        [...]
        "types": ["reflect-metadata", "webpack-env"]
    }
}
```

And that's the problem, this limits what typings are included by the compiler to the ones defined in the option :

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

That's one more check you need to make if you're in the same situation.

If that can help someone.