# NPM prune after NPM ci

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-ci

I have an innocent question :is there some interest to do a npm prune after a npm ci ? For me npm ci seems to be sufficient, no ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Depending on what you want `npm prune --production` may be beneficial since it removes all devDependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since 'npm ci' removes the existing 'node_modules' before installing, there is no need to prune.

Npm prune removes extraneous packages installed inside your node_modules folder that aren't defined inside the package.json. This can not happen when you go from an empty node_modules folder.

Comment: Do you have any reference that can prove your answer, or is it just a personal assumption?

Comment: If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically removed before npm ci begins its install. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci

Comment: What if there's a package that is added by the `ci` command, and it is still extraneous?

Comment: extraneous packages are packages that are installed inside your node_modules folder that aren't defined inside the package.json. This can not happen when you go from an empty node_modules folder.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, please edit your answer so that I can take back my downvote and change it to an upvote.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer

Answer (score 0):

but this is not valid answer of @madmed as of now, because after `npm prune` I have:

```
added 410 packages, removed 984 packages, and changed 10 packages in 32s
```

but `npm ci` desn't changes package-lock.json

So answer is: **Yes you have interest**. And I done it in my project to be sure that root package-lock.json was updated after my changes.