# build failed using react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

here is my code, it is a typescript procjet.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDatePicker from "react-datepicker";

export const DatePicker = () => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());
    return (
      <ReactDatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      />
    );
};
```

get the error when run build

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm/index.js 2:0-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Popper' in '/Users/xx/pr/node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm'

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm/index.js 3:0-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Manager' in '/Users/xx/pr/node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm'

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm/index.js 4:0-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Reference' in '/Users/xx/pr/node_modules/react-popper/lib/esm'
...
```

the react-popper is 2.3.0.
I jump to the react-popper/lib/esm/index.js and find the error,

```
Could not find a declaration file for module './Popper'.
Could not find a declaration file for module './Manager'.
Could not find a declaration file for module './Reference'. 
Could not find a declaration file for module './usePopper'.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLzYG.png)

can anyone help on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean your **node_modules** and run a `npm run install`;
References for a clean install: [How do I do a clean install (delete node_modules and install) with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589333/15080467)

Comment: Thanks. 
I find .js is not added to extensions of webpack configuration file, so the js files can not be resolved